# liquid : how to check if a variable is in a array

Tags: yaml, liquid

I am looking for something like php's in_array

I have a array, lets say

```yaml
haysack:
  - value1
  - value2
  - value3
  - value4
  - value5
```

and I want to check if needle is in haysack

```
{% assign needle = "value1" %}
{% if needle in haysack %}
   ... 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use contains with arrays

```
{% assign needle = "value1" %}
{% if haysack contains needle %}
   ... 
{% endif %}
```